# Multiple ajax to c# webmethod calls

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asmx, webmethod

I have  a jquery ajax call to a c# asmx web method, which does some processing,and internally calls more api's \ DB operation ,etc etc taking approx 20-30 seconds

**WEB METHOD**

```
[WebMethod]
public void dummy()
{
    File.Create(@"C:\test\test" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString() + ".txt");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);
}
```

**AJAX CALL**

```
$.ajax(
     {
         url:Service.asmx/dummy",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         type: "POST",
         success: function (strData) {
             alert('done');
         }
    });
```

The ajax call is within a loop which is fired 2 times, but the web method gets called only Once, so i tried `async: false`, then web method gets hit twice but after the 60 seconds delay.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Your code seems fine and should work. How did you test that the method is only hit once ?

Comment: :) because the file got created just once.

Comment: But if both calls got through the same milliseconds... You may be just overwritng the file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the delay by `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000)` in code behind and send the second `ajax` call after receiving the response from the server side.

```
$.ajax(
     {
         url:Service.asmx/dummy",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         type: "POST",
         success: function (strData) {
             alert('done');
             //send second call here
         }
         error:  function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             //send second call here if required.
         }
    });
```

If you do not have any synchronization problem for simultaneous call then you can remove delay and send multiple call simultaneouly.

Comment: Thanks for reply Adil, but the problem i am facing is that i would like to make parallel requests to the webmethod. If i wait for the response, its as good as making the call async:false, right ?

Comment: If you do not have any synchronization problem for simultaneous call then you can remove delay and send multiple call simultaneouly

Comment: Okay, that delay was a bummer,causing all sorts of issues( i still dont know why) would be great if someone can throw some light on that . I removed the delay, removed the dummy webmethod and placed actual code (calls a 3rd party api) and returns a sting, and it works.

Comment: System.Threading.Thread.Sleep block the current thread for given time and the execution of method wont finish for that time.